# Spring JPA, combine @Lock with @Transactional for synchronizing concurrent db accesses

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, concurrency

I'm implementing a workflow where an entity can be upserted as a consequence of two concurrent events:

```
public void onSomethingHappened(int entityId)
    entity = repository.findById(entityId)
    if (entity == null) {
        entity = createNew()
    }
    entity.doSomething()
    repository.save(entity)

public void onSomethingElseHappened(int entityId)
    entity = repository.findById(entityId)
    if (entity == null) {
        entity = createNew()
    }
    entity.doSomethingElse()
    repository.save(entity)
```

So what I want is to prevent that, for example, `onSomethingHappened` reads the database just right while the other method is executing, since this will lead to create an instance of the entity while `onSomethingElseHappened` is doing the same, generating a dirty read

The first thing that came into my mind is to handle this case with pessimistic locking and make both methods @Transactional and set a @Lock on `repository.findById()`. My expectation is that one of the two transactions will acquire the lock and will release it at the end of the method execution, so the other method won't complete the read until the other method has saved the entity, so that the read will produce a non-empty result

[documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Lock.html) though, seems to not provide more info about it

Another option could be using optimistic concurrency control, using @Version annotated field in the Entity and retrying one of the two operations if they raise a `OptimisticLockException`...but

- I'm not sure if this works when entity Ids are autogenerated, since both methods would create the initial versions of two different entities. Maybe I should somehow use the generatedId to compute the version number?
- Other constraints would make preferrable to not adopt this approach

So, is the pessimistic locking way viable? If not, how to make sure that optimistic locking will work in a scenario of row inserting?

Comment: Which DB? It sounds a gap lock is what you want. Usually, you can't lock a row that does not yet exist

Comment: what if you were to almost nullify the possibility of a id collision using [this algorithm](https://www.callicoder.com/distributed-unique-id-sequence-number-generator/) to generate ids?